# Find all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying the equation $5x+1 \equiv 13 ~~{\rm(mod~23)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, integers

I am doing some exercises on groups and I am having trouble trying to show why the solution to:
$$5x+1 \equiv 13 ~~{\rm(mod~26)}$$
is
$$18 + 26\mathbb{Z}$$.

Can anyone please explain? Thanks for your help.

Comment: But $23$ and $26$ look unrelated ...

Comment: ah yes sorry typo.

Comment: Which of two possible typoes?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $5\cdot 5 \equiv -1\pmod{26} \implies 5^{-1} \pmod{26} \equiv -5\pmod{26}$. Hence, we have
$$5x+1 \equiv 13\pmod{26} \implies 5x \equiv 12\pmod{26}$$
$$5x \equiv 12\pmod{26} \implies x \equiv-60\pmod{26} \equiv 18\pmod{26}$$

Answer (score 1):

Simply done :

For some $y$

$$5x = 12 + 26y$$

So taking mod 5 we can infer that for some $n$ :

$$5n = 2 + y$$

$$y = 5n - 2$$

And substituting back we get :

$$5x = 12 + 5(26)n - 26(-2)$$

$$5x = -40 + 5(26)n$$

$$x = -8 + 26n$$

And we can rewrite that as by setting $n = m+1$

$$x = 18 + 26m$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$5x\equiv 12 \mod 26$$ and this is equivalent to $$x\equiv \frac{12}{5}\equiv \frac{48}{5}\equiv\frac{74}{5}\equiv \frac{100}{5}\equiv 20 \mod 26$$

Comment: Please notice that the question has been edited.

Comment: You should have $$x \equiv \frac{12}{5} \equiv \frac{\color{red}{38}}{5} \pmod{26}$$  Following your chain of reasoning would then result in the correct answer of $18 \pmod{26}$.